# Pandas DataFrame call inside apply the same Dataframe with conditions on cuurent rows , how about performance?

Tags: python, pandas

I Have DFV with more than 50 000 rows each row are composed of about 15 columns.

I want for each row apply function using :

```
def (val,date,rang,periode):
    if periode <=10:
        if rang == 0:
            DATE = date
            return DFV[(DFV.DATE==DATE)&(DFV.VAL==val)&(DFV.PERIODE.isin(range(1,11)))].shape[0]
        else :
            DATE = dateavant2(date,rang-1)
            return DFV[(DFV.DATE==DATE)&(DFV.VAL==val)&(DFV.PERIODE.isin(range(1,11)))].shape[0]
```

and then  create in the same DFV data frame new columns by :

```
DFV["HOMAPP"]  = DFV[["VAL","DATE","PERIODE"]]\
.apply(lambda l : Howmanyapp(l["VAL"],l["DATE"],0,l["PERIODE"]),axis=1)
```

it's bad or not?

how I can improve the speed of my process for similar functions? (even loop)

Thank's in advance.

Comment: try not to use any loops. Pandas developers are clever enough to optimize their functions, so try to use built-in functions and not your inventions

Comment: I need more detail s  and please forget the loop starts by explaining the worst things inside my code.

Comment: `np.where` can replace your function.  np is in numpy library

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't understand how your code works, `Howmanyapp` in definition can get only 3 arguments, here: `.apply(lambda l : Howmanyapp(l["VAL"],l["DATE"],0,l["PERIODE"]),axis=1)` you send 4, it should stop working here.
2. Why do you use if case? can you try to use groupby + transform-count? like

```py
DFV['periode_range'] = pd.cut(DFV['PERIODE'], bins=[0,10, 16, np.inf], right=True, labels=['small', 'large', 'last'])
new_df = DFV.groupby(["VAL","DATE", 'periode_range']).count()
# here we need to merge 
DFV['periode_range'] = pd.cut(DFV['PERIODE'], bins=[0,10, np.inf], right=True, labels=['small', 'large'])
DFV = DFV.merge(new_df , on=["VAL","DATE", 'periode_range'])
```

The code above may not work, as I have not tested it. You can try to modify it, or you can attach some test data to your question so that i cat test it myself.

3. Also I did not find reference to `dateavant2` in the internet, so I do not know what to do with it, if you can help  me with that, I will adjust the code using that function.

Comment: Sorry, I copy the wrong functions. I apologize,  how about the last one?

Comment: @malouke rang is always 0 in your case, if not, you can get new column with the ```DFV['dateavant2'] = DFV.apply(lambda x: dateavant2(x['DATE'], your_rang_here-1), axis=1)```

Comment: My question is about calling the data frame inside the function to apply to the same dataframe, just that.

Comment: @malouke please check my current answer, it can be lightlly modified to give same result as your function and would be faster than what you do right now.   If you want me to modify and test it, I will need to get small piece of test data from you attached to question.